# SAP-RAP-Unmanaged: Confusion about execution of behav's read

Tags: sapui5, cds, rap

I have an unmanaged rap scenario, where the topmost root entity is covered with a projection, the corresponding behav also has a projection.

The generated implenentation of the behav created empty stubs for several methods ( like read, rba, cba, etc )... as we know it.

Furthermore I have an freestyle ui5 application ( JS ), where I use my exposed entitysets and actions defined in my published ui5 odata service ( v2 ).

The structure of the entities is hierarchical ( similar to almost every example ) with header and items.

So until now all generated method stubs of the behaviour class are empty ( except two actions, which execute just fine and do, what I want them to do )...

And, the "read" method is empty.

According to this link

https://software-heroes.com/en/blog/abap-rap-unmanaged-scenario

i read this:

[image]

Inside my ui5 clientcode, I do have an sap.m.Table containing the headers and this is done via one of the proper 3 approaches, here via items binding

```
<Table id="tabOrders" 
                  inset="false" 
                  showNoData="false"                     
                  items="{/HEADERS}"
                  mode="SingleSelectMaster"                   
                  itemPress=".onOrderTableItemPress" >
                   <columns >
```

This triggers properly the implicit read of the exposed entityset, called HEADERS.
This entityset is properly exposed in the service definition, all metadata in the client ( BAS ) is synched.

NOW: The method "read" of the behaviour class is NOT called ( breakpoint set ).

This looks like the entityset "HEADERS"  ( which actually is the topmost ROOT entity view ) is simply read, as if it was a normal CDS view, and the underlying behav and rap models are completely ignored.

If I implement an action and issue an EML-read statement on that entity in there, the method stub IS called, and returns nothing, because it is still an empty method stub.

I tried the same with an explicit "read", invoked on the odata model, this also ignores the read method of that behav class.

So somehow, the calls from my client code ( JS ) jump directly onto the entity-set, BUT it seems as if the execution simply ignores, that it is a part of an unmanaged rap scenario, and NOT STANDALONE CDS views...

Why ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your CDS view entity contains any data? SADL will first generate queries to load the data from CDS entity, if nothing is found, the behavior pool will not be reached at all.

If you use ADT, recommendation is to enable cross trace, you can easily find what went wrong from the call stack.

Comment: -  Yes, I see data in the entire cascade of the cds/entitystack. 

 - ADT ? You mean eclipse ? Where is that trace option hidden ?

Comment: sorry for late reply, I didn't monitor stackoverflow often. Yes, ADT means ABAP Development Tool, you can also use eclipse by installing adt plug in. See how to use cross trace here: https://help.sap.com/docs/ABAP_PLATFORM_NEW/c238d694b825421f940829321ffa326a/290647b75cea46f491907889251ad067.html